# How to disable PHP session cookie?

Tags: php, session

I am writing PHP code where I want to pass the session id myself using POST. I don't want a cookie to store the session, as it should get lost when the user gets out of the POST cycle.

PHP automatically sets the cookie where available. I learned it is possible to change this behaviour by setting `session.use_cookies` to 0 in `php.ini`. Unfortunately, I don't have access to that file and I also wouldn't want to break the behaviour of other scripts running on the same server.

Is there a way to disable or void the session cookie inside the PHP script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

err its possible to override the default settings of your host by creating your own .htaccess file and here's a great tutorial if you havent touched that yet
http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-htaccess.html

or if you're too lazy to learn
just create a ".htaccess" file (yes that's the filename) on your sites directory and place the following code

```
SetEnv session.use_cookies='0';
```

Comment: You could also try doing

header_remove('Set-Cookie');

after your session_start() call.

Answer (score 36):

Use [ini_set()](http://php.net/ini_set):

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', '0');
```

Or in your php.ini file:

```
session.use_cookies = 0
```

Comment: Thank you. that should solve my problem, but unfortunately, instead PHP stops in the middle of script execution now (even in the middle of html output)..

Comment: I won't tag this as being the correct answer as it made PHP defunct. Perhaps a PHP bug?

Comment: It seems that nothing happens. The htaccess solution worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can also put that setting in .htaccess so it applies to all scripts, otherwise you need to ensure that code is called on each request.

Eg.

php_value session.use_cookies 0

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the site is running Netscape Server! :(

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to be able to zap a session at a given time, use session_destroy(). If you want to completely end the session, here's a snippet copy/pasted straight out of the documentation:

```
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having trouble with PHP's documented approach to destroying a session w/ cookies.

```
// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}
```

This was resulting in my seeing the cookie set twice:

```
Set-Cookie: SESSION_NAME=deleted; expires=Sat, 08-Jan-2011 14:09:10 GMT; path=/; secure
Set-Cookie: SESSION_NAME=1_4f09a3871d483; path=/
```

As documented in the PHP comments, setting the cookie value to something other than empty ('') gets rid of the "deleted" value, but the second cookie set remained.

To get rid of that, I had to add the code suggested above:

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', '0');
```

I haven't looked at the source for sessions handling, but my guess is that setcookie(...) is bypassing the sessions module, so sessions doesn't know I called it. So, it is setting a default cookie after I set up a deleted cookie.

I was testing on a mac: PHP 5.3.6 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep  8 2011 19:34:00)

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a setup with session / header already defined from other app location, you can also remove the `Set-Cookie` HTTP header with this code block

```php
header_remove("Set-Cookie");
```

Answer (score -4):

The way to do it is to setup sessions yourself.

In the central include file that all your other files are including (you do have one of those, right?), you need to do a few things as early as is practical.

```
if( !array_key_exists('sessionid', $_POST) ) {
    // recreate the sessionid
    $sessionid = md5(rand().' '.microtime()); // Or something
} else {
    $sessionid = $_POST['sessionid'];

session_id($sessionid);
session_start();
```

Now you have to remember that as soon as you start the form, you need to include:

```
<input type='hidden' name='sessionid'><?= session_id() ?></input>
```

Comment: This is a very bad idea, just using the passed sessionid makes you prone to session fixation attacks. And it does not disable PHP's cookie-mechanism.

Comment: There is a risk in commenting old answers: that whoever created the answer might not even remember why he answered in that way.