# how to implent cookie-free domain or request?

Tags: php, cookies, image-processing, http-request

hello im trying to implant something like **static.domain.com** where we can put our image without cookie. but the problem is that im serving my image via php. like this

```
public function getIMG( $img )
{
    if ( ! file_exists( "www-static". DS ."assets". DS ."images". DS . $img ) ) {
        throw new Exception( "No such img as $img" );
    }

    $img = "/image-static". DS ."assets". DS ."images". DS . $img;
    echo '<img src="' . $img . '" />';
}
```

**can we still implant them** ? maybe using php cookie_set and somehow clear all the cookie ? but im afraid its part together with the sessions if im correct.

here is the request from firebug.

[image]

Comment: Holy crap, what hash function are you using to generate that session ID?  That's obscenely long and unnecessary.

Comment: 512 hash. ( i know its overkill ) but my team have thought about it( security above performance. ) thats why we are trying to take the performance somewhere else like serving static content good enough. etc.

Comment: How are you protecting against malicious character injection into the `$img` parameter? If an attacker supplies an `$img` like `"../../../../../config/database.conf"` or `"../../../../../var/lib/mysql/databasename.db"` this code will happily give the attacker your database username/password or database or other data that should remain private.

Comment: @sarnold yes, thanks for the concern, we are filtering from the type of data. thanks!.

Comment: hash cracking time isn't the only session performance consideration.  That session token is nearly the length of the entire rest of the headers combined.  That means more data transfer which can mean slower reaction times over high-latency networks.  sha1 is perfectly fine for session tokens, and will be a performance boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the php session cookie which gets created automatically when using sessions.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241715/how-to-disable-php-session-cookie) on how to disable it.

Comment: can we just turn it off when we do such a request, and turn it back on, im not sure what will happen if we disable it. edit* as i said the problem is im serving my image from a framework, so it is as one isn't it ?

Comment: @adam Any particular reason you want it removed? If you need sessions there is no way around it (unless you would append it to the URL instead of the cookie, im guessing that wouldn't help your concerns though)

Comment: well just following the static.domain.com told by yahoo. and it seems they are right, what for we use cookie for serving image ? http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: so somehow i have to use <img src="thefile.png"> without useing the framework, correct ?

Comment: @adam What does the framework do? Does it depend on sessions?

Comment: well it uses session to store login information ( im loggin or im not login, kinda stuff.

Comment: @adam It's possible that the cookie is set to domain `*.domain.com*`, if that is the case, you want to set the cookie domain to `domain.com`.

Comment: [`session_set_cookie_params`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php).  Use it before your `session_start`.

Answer (score 0):

You can still do something like what you have in your description. The trick is that instead of checking whether an image is in the local file system, you would check whether an image is available on a remote server.

You may want to use something like:

```
$image_headers = get_headers('http://static.domain.com/image.png'); 
if (false !== strpos($image_headers[0], '200'))
     // echo image tag if the response's status code is 200
```

Of course, constantly pinging a remote server is a costly process. So you may want to keep a local list of images that are available on static.domain.com