# Starting and accessing sessions using auto-prepend-file from .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php

I have been trying to use the 'auto-prepend-file' value to set a PHP script to be ran before every page from that directory. Currently, I'm destroying and creating a session, then setting a session variable.

But if I try to access session variables from a page, there is no value in them.

1. Can this value be prevented from being set in a .htaccess file?
2. Will the prepended script be ran when called for non-php pages aswell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can this value be prevented from being set in a .htaccess file?

It is possible to [disable session cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241715/how-to-disable-php-session-cookie) with a .htaccess file, but I doubt that's the real problem in your case. Are you sure the file is actually getting prepended at all? Try a more direct test, like adding `die('The prepended file was executed.')` to the file.

> Will the prepended script be ran when called for non-php pages aswell?

The auto_prepend_file directive only applies to files parsed by PHP. In most server configurations that will only include .php files. However, you can use the [AddHandler directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler) to make Apache execute PHP in other file types as well.

For example, if you use AddHandler to add .html as another file type that can contain PHP code, auto_prepend_file will also apply to .html files.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up solving it for me was setting the "AllowOverride" directive on my Apache configuration file. In order to allow .htaccess privileges on  given folder, you should have something like...

```
# Allow .htaccess settings
<Directory "/absolute/path/to/htaccessfolder">
    AllowOverride Options
</Directory>
```

...on httpd.conf, which allows overriding option settings from the selected directory.