# PHP $_SESSION is always empty on the production environment for all function, except one specific function

Tags: php, session

Below are functions that print `$_SESSION`.

```
public function foo() {
    print($_SESSION); 
}

public function bar() {
    print($_SESSION); 
}

public function anyOtherFunctionName() {
    print($_SESSION); 
}
```

We are facing a problem that all functions print `$_SESSION` in the local environment and `$_SESSION` is not empty for any function. In the production environment, only the `foo()` function prints `$_SESSION` containing information. `$_SESSION` in any other function is always empty.

If we change `foo()` function name to `whatever()`, `$_SESSION` is also empty in the production environment. And if we change the `bar()` function name to `foo()` function name on the production environment, `$_SESSION` which was empty, is not empty anymore.

So, on the production environment `$_SESSION` is always empty in any function name, except the name `foo()`.

On the local environment, `$_SESSION` is never empty in any function.

Is it possible that someone can configure some PHP server configuration to always empty `$_SESSION` if it is not the `foo()` function? Any idea how we can debug that when `$_SESSION` is never empty in any function name in local environment?

Comment: `$_SESSION` is superglobal, it should be visible everywhere. Did you call `session_start();` late?

Comment: Take a look into this one, probably you'll find the answer, seems that this is a configuration issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356373/how-to-disable-sessions-in-php-with-a-specific-function

Comment: You can add this code in one of function and check
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

I think session_start() function is not call at first line of page in your code. Because some server or PHP version can only get session function only at first line without space. Please check your PHP version on both local and live server